# jQuery select2 - how to get property from option?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

How can I get property from selected(!) OPTION element inside SELECT using select2 from bootstrap?

HTML:

```
<select id="select_project_type">
    <option value="1" required-property="A">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2" required-property="B">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('#select_project_type').select2({
    placeholder: $('#select_project_type').prop('placeholder')
});

$('#select_project_type').on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
    console.log(e); // Here I got all object, but I don't know how 
                    // to get required-property from selected option
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using precise CSS selectors like this:

```
$("#select_project_type option[value=1]").attr("required-property");
$("#select_project_type option[value=2]").attr("required-property")
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2cXt5/

**EDIT: to get only the property from the selected option use this selector:**

```
$("#select_project_type option:selected").attr("required-property");
```

Additionnaly you may want to use the select `change event` to find when the option changes and update ypur data.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/2cXt5/2/

Comment: Yes, but I need only required-property from selected option.

Comment: @ZaquPL Oh my bad, hold on I will fix this

Comment: @ZaquPL Edited, please tell me if it not what your are exactly looking for

Answer (score 1):

We can udpate the property to data-required-property ,

and then you could try the following code :

```
$('.select2').select2({
placeholder: $('.select2').prop('placeholder')
});

$('#select_project_type').on('select2-selecting', function(e) {
   console.log($(this).find(":selected").data('required-property')); 
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/yoyog/2/edit)